# File uploaded successfully but not showing in upload_path folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I successfully uploaded the file based on the "$this->upload->data()" message. However, the file doesn't show up in D:/Drive/webcode/uploads folder. Can anyone help out? Thank you. 
***move_uploaded_file() works, but not do_upload
[Codeigniter 3]

View(upload_form.php)

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="userfile">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Controller(Upload)

```
    function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->helper('url');

        }

    public function jobapply()
        {
            //Show view form
            $this->load->view('upload_form');
            if($this->input->post('submit')){ //Check submit button
            //Confirm file is transfered here
            echo basename($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]).'<br>';
            //Upload Process
            $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
            var_dump(is_dir($config['upload_path'])); //Check if this path exist
            //return the uploaded data after executing do_upload()
            echo "<br><pre>";
            print_r($this->upload->data()); 
            echo "</pre>";
            }
}
```

Output

```
1969.png
bool(true)
Array
(
    [file_name] => 1969.png
    [file_type] => image/png
    [file_path] => D:/Drive/webcode/uploads/
    [full_path] => D:/Drive/webcode/uploads/1969.png
    [raw_name] => 1969
    [orig_name] => 
    [client_name] => 1969.png
    [file_ext] => .png
    [file_size] => 1217976
    [is_image] => 1
    [image_width] => 
    [image_height] => 
    [image_type] => 
    [image_size_str] => 
)
```

[Image: Folder is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Ac0.jpg)

Comment: Check permissions of the target folder.

Comment: I gave full control to "everyone" in security setting for upload folder, but still no luck. By the way, thanks for sharing your solution. @RohitGhotkar

Answer (score 0):

Add $config['allowed_types'] = '*'; and check.

Comment: Still not working, I'm going to share my workaround in my post. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

> **Solved** without using CI upload

Just use below in Controller:

```
$path = './upload/';
$temp = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($temp, $path . $name);
echo 'Success';
```

Thats it, I wouldn't bother if using CI Upload library or not, as long as it works. Cheers.